# Can I have multiple service workers both intercept the same fetch request?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm writing a library which I will provide for 3rd parties to run a service worker on their site. It needs to intercept all network requests but I want to allow them to build their own service worker if they like.

Can I have both service workers intercept the same fetches and provide some kind of priority/ordering between them? Alternatively is there some other pattern I should be using?

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No, you can not. Only one service worker per scope is allowed to be registered so [the latest kick the previous one out](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-registration-concept) unless the scope is more specific, in this case, the request is attended by the most specific only.

Nevertheless, you can attach multiple `fetch` handlers and they all will process the request so maybe you can write your functionality in a separated script and let the user's service worker to include your file via [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts).

The first handler calling `event.respondWith()` synchronously (actually, you can not call this method asynchronously) wins and the remaining handlers trying to call will throw.

Prioritization and coordination requires middleware. You can check [ServiceWorkerWare](https://github.com/fxos-components/serviceworkerware) or [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox).

Comment: Any idea whether the replacement for `sw-toolbox`, WorkBox, supports the notion of middleware?

Comment: Hello, could you update the first link? it's broken.

Comment: @Salva I have a main website service worker with scope '/' and another service worker on game pages '/game' with a specific scope. Yet the fetch handlers of the main service worker are called. Can I check anything else to make sure that my /game service worker is given preference?

Comment: However, many service workers can run  loaded from the same HTML page, on the same domain but different scopes.

Comment: Make sure the `scope` value ends with a slash.