# How to register multiple service worker in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have converted my Angular 6 application into Progressive Web Apps, by registering the service worker in app.module .ts but also i am registering one more service worker for firebase push notification but i am unable to do that, where and how to register it?

I have tried one solution by referring following link : 
https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/how-to-use-a-firebase-fcm-service-worker-with-angular-s-ngsw-service-worker/

1 In file :  app.module.ts I have register service worker like this :

ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { enabled: environment.production }),

2. In index.html wrote firebase push notification code.
3. In angular.json invoked js files :

   ```
     "assets": [
         "src/favicon.ico",
         "src/assets",
         "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
         "src/manifest.webmanifest"
       ],
   ```

In console->application

showing only one service worker registered i.e
firebase-messaging-sw.js .

Comment: Do you have ngsw-config.json in your project ?

Comment: As it stands you [can't register more than one SW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000127/can-i-have-multiple-service-workers-both-intercept-the-same-fetch-request) in a scope. You'll have to work on combining the code from the two SWs into one.

Comment: yes I have the ngsw-config.json.

Comment: Yes I have refereed the given link to combine the service worker but  still not working . (https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/how-to-use-a-firebase-fcm-service-worker-with-angular-s-ngsw-service-worker/ ) showing me an error  **combined-worker.js service worker not found**