# How add multiple service worker on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, service-worker, flutter-web

I want to add a service worker (in addition to the existing "flutter_service_worker").

The problem I have is that I can't get both to be active at the same time. I don't quite understand the scope issue.

When I register my service worker, I do the following in the index.html: `navigator.serviceWorker.register("./sw.js", { Scope: "/". });`

Then I install it and activate it in cache, but it overlaps the original.

Which scope should be used to keep both service workers active?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have multiple service workers both intercept the same fetch request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000127/can-i-have-multiple-service-workers-both-intercept-the-same-fetch-request)

Comment: No, because the main worker id "flutter _service_worker" and this its generated on build instruction. I cant edit before to add "importscripts..."