# How to have a service worker for a PWA if your 3rd party push notifications supplier already has a service worker?

Tags: service-worker

I currently use Pushwoosh for my push notifications in my web-app, which I've successfully set up.

I'm in the process of converting the web-app to a PWA, and want to set up my own service worker so that I can control caching and a few other things.

The Pushwoosh service worker needs to be in the root level. From what I understand there can only be one service worker per scope. If this is the case, what's the done thing when you need to have your own service worker but you already have one via a 3rd party service? Would a solution be to download the Pushwoosh one from their cdn, add my own code requirements to the end of it and serve it from my own server, or is there a better solution?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have multiple service workers both intercept the same fetch request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000127/can-i-have-multiple-service-workers-both-intercept-the-same-fetch-request)

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn - Pushwoosh replied showing me how to set up their service worker to have a different scope to root level (see below), which should allow the service worker I create in root to run.

--
Modify the initialization script by adding a parameter serviceWorkerUrl: “/push-notifications/pushwoosh-service-worker.js” where /push-notifications/pushwoosh-service-worker.js is the path to pushwoosh-service-worker.js file -- I'll try this and if it doesn't work I'll look deeper into the direction you posted